# Duplicated first item in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm having an issue when loading a list in a recycler view that is into an Alert Dialog with custom layout. The problem is that the first item repeats two times and I don't understand why.

If somebody can help me and the community to understand why this happens with a good explanation?

Screenshot of the problem:[image: Click here]

AccountActivity witch calls the dialogue:

```
public class AccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context context;
    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    List<UserAvatar> userAvatarList = new ArrayList<>();

    private User user;
    private UserAvatar userAvatar;

    private TextView textViewAccountUsername;
    private TextView textViewAccountFollowersNumber;
    private TextView textViewAccountFollowingNumber;
    private TextView textViewAccountDescription;

    private ImageButton imageButtonAccountBackArrow;
    private ImageView imageViewAccountAvatar;

    private AlertDialog alertDialogChooseAvatar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.sharedPreferencesDocName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bindUI();
        setListeners();
        getLocalData();
        getUserAvatar();
    }

    private void bindUI(){
        textViewAccountUsername = findViewById(R.id.textViewAccountUsername);
        textViewAccountFollowersNumber = findViewById(R.id.textViewAccountFollowersNumber);
        textViewAccountFollowingNumber = findViewById(R.id.textViewAccountFollowingNumber);
        textViewAccountDescription = findViewById(R.id.textViewAccountDescription);
        imageButtonAccountBackArrow = findViewById(R.id.imageButtonAccountBackArrow);
        imageViewAccountAvatar = findViewById(R.id.imageViewAccountAvatar);
    }

    private void setListeners(){
        imageButtonAccountBackArrow.setOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());
        imageViewAccountAvatar.setOnClickListener(v -> showChooseAvatarDialog());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AccountActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    private void getLocalData(){
        user = gson.fromJson(sharedPreferences.getString("user", ""), User.class);
        if(user != null){
            setLocalData();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.generic_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void getUserAvatar() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Response response;
                try {
                    response = UserAvatarRequests.getAvatar(context, user.getAvatar_id());
                    String responseBody = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string();
                    responseBody = responseBody.replace("\r\n", "");
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        UserAvatar userAvatar = gson.fromJson(responseBody, UserAvatar.class);
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("userAvatar", gson.toJson(userAvatar)).apply();
                        getAvatars();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    private void getAvatars(){
        Thread threadGetAvatars = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Response response;
                try {
                    response = UserAvatarRequests.getAvatars(context);
                    String responseBody = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string();
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        userAvatarList.clear();
                        JSONArray responseArray = new JSONArray(responseBody);
                        for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {
                            String jsonObjectString = responseArray.getJSONObject(i).toString();
                            userAvatarList.add(gson.fromJson(jsonObjectString, UserAvatar.class));
                        }
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("userAvatars", gson.toJson(userAvatarList)).apply();
                        getApiData();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        threadGetAvatars.start();
    }

    private void getApiData(){
        Thread threadGetUserById = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Response response;
                try {
                    response = UserRequests.getUserById(context, user.getId());
                    String responseBody = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string();
                    responseBody = responseBody.replace("\r\n", "");
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        user = gson.fromJson(responseBody, User.class);
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("user", gson.toJson(user)).apply();
                        setApiData();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        threadGetUserById.start();
    }

    private void setLocalData(){
        textViewAccountUsername.setText(user.getUsername());
        textViewAccountDescription.setText(user.getDescription());
    }

    private void setApiData(){
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    textViewAccountUsername.setText(user.getUsername());
                    textViewAccountDescription.setText(user.getDescription());
                    userAvatar = userAvatarList.get(user.getAvatar_id());
                    Picasso.get().load(userAvatar.getAvatar_url()).into(imageViewAccountAvatar);
                });
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    private void showChooseAvatarDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AccountActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.change_avatar));
        final View customLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_choose_avatar, null);
        builder.setView(customLayout);
        alertDialogChooseAvatar = builder.create();
        ChooseAvatarAdapter chooseAvatarAdapter = new ChooseAvatarAdapter(AccountActivity.this, userAvatarList, alertDialogChooseAvatar, imageViewAccountAvatar);
        RecyclerView recyclerViewChooseAvatar = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewChooseAvatar);
        recyclerViewChooseAvatar.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 3));
        recyclerViewChooseAvatar.setAdapter(chooseAvatarAdapter);
        alertDialogChooseAvatar.show();
    }
}
```

Alert Dialog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewChooseAvatar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Recyclerview item XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewChooseAvatar"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

RecyclerView adapter:

```
    public class ChooseAvatarAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChooseAvatarAdapter.ChooseAvatarAdapterViewHolder> {

    private final Context context;
    private final List<UserAvatar> userAvatarList;
    private final AlertDialog alertDialogAvatar;
    private final ImageView imageViewAvatar;

    public ChooseAvatarAdapter(Context context, List<UserAvatar> userAvatarList, AlertDialog alertDialogAvatar, ImageView imageViewAvatar) {
        this.context = context;
        this.userAvatarList = userAvatarList;
        this.alertDialogAvatar = alertDialogAvatar;
        this.imageViewAvatar = imageViewAvatar;
    }

    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public ChooseAvatarAdapter.ChooseAvatarAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ChooseAvatarAdapterViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_choose_avatar_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ChooseAvatarAdapter.ChooseAvatarAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Picasso.get()
                .load(userAvatarList.get(position).getAvatar_url())
                .into(holder.imageViewChooseAvatar);
        holder.imageViewChooseAvatar.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            alertDialogAvatar.dismiss();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.confirm_avatar_change))
                    .setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.yes), (dialog, which) -> {
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.sharedPreferencesDocName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        User user = gson.fromJson(sharedPreferences.getString("user", ""), User.class);
                        user.setAvatar_id(position);
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("user", gson.toJson(user)).apply();
                        Thread thread = new Thread() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Response response;
                                try {
                                    response = UserRequests.editUserAvatar(context, user.getId(), position);
                                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        ((AccountActivity) context).runOnUiThread(() -> Picasso.get()
                                                .load(userAvatarList.get(position).getAvatar_url())
                                                .into(imageViewAvatar));
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        thread.start();
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.no), (dialog, which) -> dialog.cancel())
                    .create()
                    .show();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userAvatarList.size();
    }

    public static class ChooseAvatarAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageViewChooseAvatar;

        public ChooseAvatarAdapterViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageViewChooseAvatar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewChooseAvatar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this Loop  for (int i = 0; i <= responseArray.length(); i++)

Comment: For me it's not working

Comment: did you check and make sure there is no duplicate?

Comment: Okay, so the problem was that the API had the images in the cache. And I've made one image change and it was still loading from the cache. Cloudflare had to hard the cache.